# Fluent nHibernate required files and linux

Tags: nhibernate, fluent

I've downloaded the fluent hibernate 1.2 zip file from the website.
It contains various files, amongst them

NHibernate.dll
FluentNHibernate.dll
Castle.Core.dll
Remotion.Data.Linq.dll
Antlr3.Runtime.dll
Iesi.Collections.dll
NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll

Q1) Are all these files required for doing a simple application?. By simple I mean that the db contains a few tables that doesn't need complicated queries and has limited levels/amounts of reference keys and joins.

Q2) Does fluent nHibernate run on mono on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. no; see [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx) for what's needed and what's optional.
2. it runs wherever you can run (and develop) .net programs (i.e it, obviouslly, needs .net runtime environment).